# ContractNotFound: No contract deployed at

Tags: python, chainlink

I have been involved in the chainlink bootcamp and trying to finishing the final 'Exercise 3: Putting it all together'.

However, I am stuck running:

```
brownie run scripts/price_exercise_scripts/01_deploy_price_exercise.py --network kovan
```

`ContractNotFound: No contract deployed at 0xF4030086511a5bEEa4966F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c`

Printed `contract_type._name` is a mock address returned from `MockV3Aggregator which also doesn't make sense, why the code calls this logic.

```
def get_contract(contract_name):

contract_type = contract_to_mock[contract_name]
if network.show_active() in NON_FORKED_LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
    if len(contract_type) <= 0:
        deploy_mocks()
    contract = contract_type[-1]
else:
    try:
        contract_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][contract_name]

        contract = Contract.from_abi(
            contract_type._name, contract_address, contract_type.abi
        )
    except KeyError:
        print(
            f"{network.show_active()} address not found, perhaps you should add it to 
       the config or deploy mocks?")
        print(
            f"brownie run scripts/deploy_mocks.py --network {network.show_active()}"
        )
return contract
```

I am struggling to understand this error message, should this command not be deploying contracts? I.e they should already already exist on the kovan network?

Any insights welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem - I was using the ethereum mainnet address instead of the correct kovan network address for btc / usd price.

Changing the `btc_usd_price_feed` value to `0x6135b13325bfC4B00278B4abC5e20bbce2D6580e` in the config.yml fixed this issue for me.

[price feed addresses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/)

Answer (score 6):

Because address of ganache is reset(by close and open again) and brownie use its own files which is gone
Remove files and directory in `build/deployments` solve for me.

Comment: I didn't want to completely remove all files in `build/deployments` since map.json tracks deployments to all networks (and I had some dpeloyments to testnest). Therefore, I removed contract addresses in map.json for my previous ganache session and removed files from the ganache network id folder. `build/deployments/5777` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .openzeppelin/unknown-YOUR-NetworkId.json !!!

This happens especially at deploying upgradeable contracts into Parachain EVM.